# Angular directives - watching directive's parent controller (require) doesn't trigger $watch callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a custom angular table directive, and came upon a curious problem. I have a parent directive `parentDir`, which has multiple child elements `childDir` inside it. When a `childDir` is clicked, it calls the parent's `sortByKey` function, which changes the `sorting` variable of the controller, and later on is supposed to sort the data depending on the clicked column.

The problem is, in `childDirs`, I'm $watching this the parent's `sorting` variable, but the callback function doesn't trigger when the variable value changes. Instead, it seems to queue the callback until something happens in either the parent directive controller's $scope or its parent $scope - so for example, changing an input with an `ng-model` triggers all of the queued $watch callbacks.

So far I've tried to call `$scope.$apply()` in the `sortByKey` function (which doesn't work) and in the watch callback (which obviously doesn't work since it's not getting called). I'm kinda stumped on why the callback isn't triggering since it's the first time I've ever encountered this behaviour.

[Here's a link to the plunker demonstrating the behaviour](https://plnkr.co/edit/crlqSw01QWE3E8Y7VhDW?p=preview). Open the console, and then click on the "Hello", "Hello 2" and "Hello 3" texts. You can see in the console that the `sortByKey` function is being called properly, but there's no logging from the `$watch` callback. Then change the input's value, and you can see the callback function `console.logs`.

**To summarize:**

- `$watch()` callback function isn't being triggered in a child directive until parent scope is updated
- adding `$scope.$apply` calls doesn't help
- The wanted outcome is for the `show` text to appear after the clicked text as the text is clicked, and to disappear from all the other texts

Comment: You must call _scope.$apply()_ at the end of _.bind('click')_.

Comment: @AndrewD. Thank you, that did the trick!